# Is there a way to pass options as an array to find command in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, find, gnu-findutils

In `rsync` I can just define my exclusions/options in an array and use those arrays in the subsequent command, e. g.

`rsync "${rsyncOptions[@]}" "${rsyncExclusions[@]}" src dest`

I wanted to achieve the same using the `find` command but I couldn't find a way to make it work:

```
findExclusions=(
    "-not \( -name '#recycle' -prune \)"
    "-not \( -name '#snapshot' -prune \)"
    "-not \( -name '@eaDir' -prune \)"
    "-not \( -name '.TemporaryItems' -prune \)"
)
LC_ALL=C /bin/find src -mindepth 1 "${findExclusions[@]}" -print
```

In whatever combination I try to define the array (single vs double quotes, escaping parentheses) I always end up with an error:

```
find: unknown predicate `-not \( -name '#recycle' -prune \)'
# or
find: paths must precede expression: ! \( -name '#recycle' -prune \)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that `"-not \( -name '#recycle' -prune \)"` is not one argument, it is 6 arguments. You could write it like so:

```
findExclusions=(
    -not '(' -name '#recycle' -prune ')'
    -not '(' -name '#snapshot' -prune ')'
)
```

Comment: Why does find parse the bracket correctly when it is enclosed within single quotes but not when escaped?

Comment: You _can_ use the backslash escape for the parenthesis, instead of single quotes, I just thought the quotes were less ugly. The issue was really the quoting around the whole line. All these escapes and quoting are parsed by the shell (bash,zsh,etc), `find` does not see any of it in this case.